# Decision node on TikZ (diamond)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to find a way to tame decision nodes (diamond shape) but I just can't do a thing! If I put a formula inside the diamond and if that formula is a little big the shape just grows like a square and becomes to high.

I want the decision node to look like this

[image]

http://sixsigmaspc.com/protectedimages/blockdiagram-flowchart-symbols.gif

and not like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, text badly centered, inner sep=3pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [decision] {$\lVert f(\mathbf{x}^{0}) \rVert < \varepsilon_{g}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that is compilable as provided.

Comment: See `aspect ratio` at page 177 of pgfmanual

Comment: The key is named `shape aspect` (or just `aspect`), not `aspect ratio`.

Comment: link is now broken..

Answer (score 57):

There is an `aspect` option for the diamond shape, which sets the target ration of the height and width. By default it is one. See section 48.3 “Geometric Shapes” in the manual (v2.10).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw, diamond, aspect=2] {$\lVert f(\mathbf{x}^{0}) \rVert < \varepsilon_{g}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]